# Jquery - if element contains a class, add HTML after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've got a booking `form.booking-wrap` with 2 elements in it, `div#booking` and then `div.quantity`

```
<form class="booking-wrap"> 
    <div id="booking"></div>
    /* insert div#message IF div.quantity is present inside div.booking-wrap */ 
    <div class="quantity"></div>
</form>
```

The `div.quantity` is only present dynamically for some bookings.

What I am trying to achieve is that if the `div.quantity` is present, then I would like to insert an additional html `div#message`, but this new div should appear after `div#booking` and before `div.quantity`

I am trying the following jQuery:

```
if($('.booking-wrap:has(div.quantity)')){
  $('#booking' ) .after( '<div id="message">Message</div>');
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I then tried this:

```
$('.booking-wrap:has(div.quantity)').append($('<div id="message">Message</div>'));
```

This works and the new div appears, however it is just next to the quantity div.

How can I get it to show after the `#booking` , but before `.quantity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any selector returns an object, you should check the *length* property of the returned object. Like `$('.booking-wrap:has(div.quantity)').length`

Though, I prefer `$('.booking-wrap > div.quantity').length`

```js
if($('.booking-wrap > div.quantity').length){
  $('#booking').after('<div id="message">Message</div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="booking-wrap">
  <div id="booking">booking</div>
  <div class="quantity">quantity</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Btw what does the length property do?

Comment: @JoeBloggs, the selector returns object, that is why you have to check the *length* property:)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `prepend` instead of append, since the selector `$('.booking-wrap:has(div.quantity)` will return the `(div.quantity)` element.

Example:

```
$('.booking-wrap:has(div.quantity)').prepend($('<div id="message">Message</div>'));
```

Comment: Many thanks Nikola, I'll go with Mamun's answer for this one ..

Comment: Using prepend is simpler and cleaner, but I don't mind :"D Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "hasClass()" jQuery function to check class is exist or not:

Try This

```
if($( ".booking-wrap" ).children('div').hasClass( "quantity" )){
  jQuery('<div id="message">Message</div>').insertAfter('.booking');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This jQuery.

```
if($(".quantity").length ){
    $('#booking' ).after( '<div id="message">Message</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the div you are adding within a function.

```
        if($('.booking-wrap:has(div.quantity)')){
            $( "#booking" ).after(function() {
                return '<div id="message">Message</div>';
            });
        }
```